# MongoDB One-to-Many and Many-to-One relations in Spring Boot Project

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, embedded-documents

please how can I add relations in a mongoDB cause I just start using it. For example **Comment id is a foreign key**:

```
 @Document
    class Comment {

        @Id
        private String id;
        private String text;
        private String author;

        // constructors, getters and setters are ommited
    }

    @Document
    class Article {
        @Id
        private String id;
        @DBRef(lazy = true)
        @CascadeSave
        private List<Comment> comments;
        private String title;
        private String text;

        // constructors, getters and setters are ommited
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalence of the JPA annotation @OneToMany and @ManyToMany is @DBRef